# How can I develop a simple TCG game using Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, game-development

Learning Android Dev

Hello, I'm new to programming and at the moment I am looking to make a simple Card Game (TCG) but I am completely lost on the 'how-to'.

I am using Android Studio, but I know mostly the basics of how to program in Kotlin, but is it really possible to mage a game using Androi Studio Kotlin?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.